# TCA785 obsolete, replacement?

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, phase, replacement, alternatives

I am looking to redesign an old circuit diagram's phase control IC. I can't find any ICs that can act as a replacement for this item:
[TCA785](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/875/tca785.pdf).

What should I look for in an IC for phase control? It is something very new to me.
I am converting the old schematic into my own drawing, and will attach it soon.

Comment: In the past I used the TCA785 a lot. What is the type of your load? Ex. resistive, heating, light (incandescent. halogen, LED), inductive (single-phase motor, universal motor), ....

Comment: I believe it is inductive, it has a sinusoidal output with a leading voltage peak before current.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this replacement for a few units, or many? If only for a few, the easiest way might be to buy the same part. It's no longer available from official distributors, but there seem to be still quite some stock available from [non authorized distributors](https://octopart.com/search?q=TCA785&currency=USD&specs=0).

Note that some of those distributors might not be reliable (if unsure, you might order from a few (using a safe payment method) and hope at least one delivers).

Note that in this solution, there is also a risk of fake chips or cheap copies : do not use if malfunctioning can cause safety issues.

If this does not solve your problem, then you need at least to look which of the many outputs you are really using (you might not need all of them). And you will probably not get any answer here (in fact, I would advice you edit your question to get it more about how to redesign, asking explicitly for part recommendations is a good way to get your question closed)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that part alternatives was an issue. It is a tag actually on this forum.